# Posterior pointwise uncertainty of multivariate normal-Wishart (variational GMM)

Tags: bayesian, references, posterior, gaussian-mixture-distribution, wishart-distribution

Given a variational mixture of Gaussians (as per, e.g., Chapter 10 of Bishop, 2006), we can compute the posterior predictive pdf:
$$
\left\langle p(x|\alpha,\beta,\nu,\mu,V) \right\rangle
$$
where $\alpha,\beta,\nu,\mu,V$ are the parameters of the posterior Dirichlet distribution and of the multivariate normal-Wishart posterior. The equation above can be evaluated analytically and happens to be a mixture of $t$ distributions (*).

However, I am interested in computing the *variance* of the posterior pdf at a given point $x$, which boils down to computing:

$$
\left\langle p(x|\alpha,\beta,\nu,\mu,V)^2 \right\rangle.
$$

The posterior covariance of a Dirichlet distribution has a simple analytical form (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution)), so the only thing I need is the expected square pdf of a normal-Wishart draw. However, I cannot find references for it and the derivation from scratch seems quite involved (not even sure if it would be analytical, but I'd be happy with some approximation); I would rather see if someone has already done it. Any pointer?

The rationale is that I want a principled estimate of the relative reliability of the variational distribution at a given point $x$. I expect the above formulas to yield high relative reliability in the bulk of the distribution, and low relative reliability in the tails and for mixture components with only a few points. I am also happy if you have alternative ideas on how to achieve this.

---

(*) For those interested, derivation of the posterior predictive pdf for each mixture component can be found for example [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf), and due to the variationally induced factorization of the Dirichlet posterior and the normal-Wishart posterior, computing the expectation over different components follows easily.